# Does latitude affect the sunset times between binary stars

Tags: binary-star

Basically, if a binary system's stars sunset an hour apart at the equator, would they still set an hour apart in a much farther north latitude where the daylight lasts longer or is it still an hour between sunsets?

Comment: Sunrise, sunset, length of day, etc depend on a celestial object's declination and viewer's latitude. Since a binary system's stars could easily have very different declinations, it's even possible that both stars rise and set at the equator (of a given planet for which we've defined latitude), but one of them is circumpolar near the poles. Many other combinations are possible.

Comment: Thank you for a response.  What I'm asking for is this:  If for instaonce a set of binary stars have a sunset an hour apart at the equator of a planet, would their sunset on the same day be farther apart in a northern latitude if the daylight was more hours there?  So if daylight at the equator was 15 hours and at this northern latitude it was 21 hours, and the first star set an hour before the second at the equator, would it be an hour apart on the same day in the northern location or progressively more based on the amount of daylight hours?

Comment: Yes: the time between sunset of one star and the other star does depend on latitude. They could set an hour apart at the equator and 5 hours apart at a higher latitude.